# Delete duplicate array elements

Tags: javascript

i have the following loops that goes through an array.

```
for(var j=0; j<10;j++) {
  for(var k=0; k<10; k++) {

    if(final[k]==ya[j]){
      final[k].changeRankScore((ya[j].score + final[k].score)/2);

    }else{

    }
  }
}
```

There are two array with 10 elements. I am checking if there is a duplicate element which is found in final. If yes, change the score of final of the duplicate element and do not add it to final. If no, we can add the element to final.

One of the possible ways i thought of doing it was, to tag the element to add to the array later.

Is there a better way of doing this?

EDIT:

```
Final = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 } ; 
ya = { 2 , 8, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12 } ;
```

I am looping through the array Ya. If the element is also found in array Final, increase the score of that element (since it is an object). If it is not found, just push the element from array Ya, to the array final.

In this case, number 2 and 7 from array Ya are duplicates. Consequently, the score associated with those numbers in array final should be increased while the rest of the elements of array Ya should be pushed to final. The array should then become

```
Final = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}
```

Comment: create a demo in jsfiddle.net with some sample data that provides overview of problem. Explanation is not clear at all

Comment: What you have won't work in most cases because `==` will only compare 2 objects correctly if they're actually references to the same object.  Have you tried to test it at all?

Comment: Sorry, i meant to compare a property of the objet such as final[k].url with ya[j].url and it works successfully. However, once i know ya[j] is already present in final. i want to remove it and concatenate rest of the array with final.

Comment: perhaps you just want to create new array...still not clear what overall issue is. Show everyone with some simplified data

Comment: added some sample data

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data isn't quite valid. Is this what you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/B74Gm/

```
var final = {
    1: {score:0},
    2: {score: 2},
    3: {score: 0},
    4: {score: 5},
    5: {score: 1},
    6: {score: 10}, 
    7: {score: 10}
},

ya = {
    2: {score: 2},
    10: {score: 3}, 
    4: {score: 0},
    15: {score: 0},
    6: {score: 4},
    17: {score: 5}
}; 

for (var i in ya) {
    final[i] = final[i] || {score: 0};
    final[i].score += ya[i].score;
}
```

Comment: You got the sample data right but the rest not. In your sample data, there is a '2' in ya and final. Essentially, im trying to merge ya with final but not the duplicates. In this case, 2,4,6 is not going to be merged there. When there is a duplicate, let's say 2, it goes inthe final array and look for 2 and increase its score by 1.

Comment: So given this data, by the end final[2].score should equal 3?

Comment: Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726889/removing-duplicate-elements-in-two-arrays-while-assigning-a-greater-score

i tried to explain it into greater detail. And yes, you are right. While still merging the rest of the array ya.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use any framework, thats the code:

```
function mix(first_arr, second_arr) {
    for(i = 0; i < second_arr.length; i++) {
        if(first_arr.indexOf(second_arr[i]) == -1) {
            first_arr.push(second_arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return first_arr;
}
```

See in action http://jsfiddle.net/jwAmA/

PD: Use arrays [] instead of objects {}