# Removing duplicate elements in two arrays while assigning a greater score

Tags: javascript

I have 2 arrays which contains objects as follows.

```
var arrayl = {
 1: {url:google.com, score:0},
 2: {url:bing.com, score: 2},
 3: {url:yahoo.com, score: 0},
 4: {url:facebook.com, score: 5},
 5: {url:dopgile.com, score: 1},
 6: {url:ask.com, score: 10}, 
 7: {url:duckduckgo.com, score: 10}
},

array2 = {
 1: {url:google.com, score: 2},
 2: {url:facebook.com, score: 3}, 
 3: {url:twitter.com, score: 0},
 4: {url:duckduckgo.com, score: 0},
 5: {url:mamma.com, score: 4},
 6: {url:myspace.com, score: 5}
};
```

Array 1 and Array 2 both have unique elements within themselves. However there are duplicates among them.

I want to merge Array 2 with Array 1 in such a way as to increase the score of the duplicate element in Array 1 by 1 when it occurs.

For example, google.com is present in array 2 and array 1. When the merging process begins, it increases the score of the first element of array 1 which is google.com to 1 instead of 0. It shouldn't add the first element of array2 to it since it is a duplicate.

Similarly, the elements 2,3,5,6 will be merged without increasing any scores as there isn't a duplicate in the array1. Howevever, duckduckgo is a duplicate and will increase the score of duckduckgo.com in array1[7] to 11 and not add it to the array.

Finally, the array should be:

```
var arrayl = {
 1: {url:google.com, score:1},
 2: {url:bing.com, score: 2},
 3: {url:yahoo.com, score: 0},
 4: {url:facebook.com, score: 5},
 5: {url:dopgile.com, score: 1},
 6: {url:ask.com, score: 10}, 
 7: {url:duckduckgo.com, score: 11}
 8: {url:facebook.com, score: 3}, 
 9: {url:twitter.com, score: 0},
 10: {url:mamma.com, score: 4},
 11: {url:myspace.com, score: 5}
```

},

I have tried going through the array with the following loops.

```
for(var j=0; j<10;j++) {
 for(var k=0; k<10; k++) {
  if(array1[k].url==array2[j].url){

   array1[k].changeRankScore(array1[k].score+1);

  }else{
   //this is the case where it is not the same. Ideally i should just push it to array1    but since it's a double loops, finally all the items will be added from array2 to array1 with several duplicates. 
  }
 }
}
```

Help please.

Comment: Your example result has two facebook.com entries, I assume that was a mistake.

Comment: @Zeta That question doesn't include the incrementing of scores when matching elements are found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object mapping urls to elements of array1:

```
var a1_assoc = {};
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    a1_assoc[array1[i].url] = array1[i];
}
```

Then use it in your merge step:

```
for (i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    var url = array2[i].url;
    if (a1_assoc[url]) {
        a1_assoc[url].score++;
    } else {
        array1.push(array2[i]);
    }
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/H7Gj8/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing a double loop, do a single loop over the second array. For each item, check if the url of your current item is contained within array1 - then perform the first or second case as you desire. This way you only perform an operation on every array2 entry once.

Comment: How? To check if the item is in the second array, don't i have loop through it again?

Comment: @Mozammil I haven't used javascript much, but surely it has a `contains` or `indexOf` or `get` that will let you see if an item exists in an array by key or by value?